# android studio res/menu crash

Tags: android, android-studio, menu, crash

I'm attempting to create a custom menu bar with a simple button to add a new item to a database.

I create the menu folder in the res directory, I create an xml file with the name menu_list.xml

Once I open the file and press a key, android studio goes into meltdown (doesn't crash) Just freezes, I can't figure it out, i've no idea what i'm doing wrong.

I'm hoping someone here can tell me what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Without any code nobody will be able to help you. Post you XML code along with your Java class

Comment: did you even read the question dude? I have no XML to post because it freezes before i can type anything.

Comment: Try with different name of the file. Try to download different android studio versions. Try it on different computer with the same project (if you don't have access to any you can use virtual machine).

Comment: Sorry man, I did actually miss read the question...long day. What Android Studio version are you on?

Comment: Android studio 1.5.1 (Dec 1, 2015)
JRE: 1.8.0 @tjshakespeare

Comment: I attempted a different file name in the same directory "res/menu" and got the same crash, currently installing studio on my laptop @Teodor

Comment: Please see in the bottom right corner for error logs in Android Studio.

Comment: Okay so i did the same thing on my laptop, and recreated the crash exctactly the same way as my desktop
It seems like i'm putting this menu folder in the wrong place.

Comment: I've given up, I've done something critically wrong. I can't access error logs because there are none, the android studio software freezes and will not respond, in any, way, shape or form.

I've installed android studio on my laptop and encountered EXACTLY the same error.
Which makes no sense because I don't actually do anything other than create a file and attempt to type inside it.

Am I breaking some sort of new convention, do you no longer need a res/menu folder to define menu related stuff. @teodor

Comment: Can you record your screen of what exactly you are doing. I will try to reproduce it on my side too.

Comment: [link](https://youtu.be/Vuv_nWqxDpM) I recorded exactly what I did a produce the crash. Sorry about the no audio @Teodor

Comment: @PhilipMather For resource type select 'menu' not 'values'. Also try to close the Preview view. I think it's crashing because of the Preview view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after a lot of sleep I it came to me, I've managed to resolve this.

I was inherriting my styles from theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar instead of Theme.AppCompat. So when I was trying to create / edit themes for the actionbar android studio seemed to freak out and would just freeze.

Stupid mistake, horrible results. 
Thanks for all that attempted to help.